# Nested mappings not printed as "nested" when retrieving index info?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have an index with mappings defined like so:

```
  "mappings": {
      "profile": {
        "properties": {
          "_key": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "groups": {
            "type": "nested",
            "include_in_parent": True,
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

But when I try to view the index details in the API (`localhost:9200/myindex`), the mapping of `groups` doesn't print out the `"type"` and `"include_in_parent"` field at all. Is that normal? e.g.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:9201/myindex/profile/_mapping?pretty
Response:
{
    "myindex" : {
        "mappings" : {
            "profile" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "_key" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "username" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "groups" : {   // where is "nested"?
                        "properties" : {
                            "name" : {
                                "type" : "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also having trouble doing nested queries on `groups`. I get error like `nested object under path [groups] is not of nested type` when trying the following query:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/profile/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "groups",
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "groups.name": "foo"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I make sure I've defined my mapping correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I created Index like

```
PUT myindex
```

I PUT my mapping like this

```
PUT myindex/_mapping/profile
{
  "profile": {
    "properties": {
      "_key": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "username": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "groups": {
        "type": "nested",
        "include_in_parent": true,
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you will get expected results when you do

```
GET myindex/profile/_mapping
```

**Note** : I used Marvel-Sense